# CSS menu with custom image or icon on every button

Tags: html, css

I have created Html menu as follow

```
<a href="./football.html">Football</a>
<a href="./basketball-.html">Basketball</a>
<a href="./baseball.html">Baseball</a>
```

then my css file is as follow:

```
#main-nav a
{     
   display: block;
   float: left;
   margin: 125px 0px 0px 0px;
   color: #666666;
   border: 1px #C0C0C0 solid;
   background-color: #EEEEEE;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
   width: 106px;
   height: 78px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: 78px;
   text-align: center;
}
#main-nav a:hover, #main-nav .active
{
   color: #666666;
   background-color: #C0C0C0;
   border: 1px #C0C0C0 solid;
}
```

I am trying to customize it a bit more by adding 30*30 icon of football etc in each corresponding button

i have tried to make every image as a Div and use position to make it in the corresponding button but this solution is fragile and not the best option.

can idea of better solution?

Comment: Cant u use image as bg image?

Comment: @Sowmya no want it as icon below the button text not as bg

Comment: U mean below the button?? out of the box?

Comment: @Sowmya no inside the box just below the text in the button eg: football then football icon below it all inside the botton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    #main-nav a
    {     
       display: block;
       float: left;
       margin: 125px 0px 0px 0px;
       color: #666666;
       border: 1px #C0C0C0 solid;
       font-family: Arial;
       font-size: 13px;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       text-decoration: none;
       width: 115px;
       height: 78px;
       vertical-align: middle;
       line-height: 78px;
       text-align: center; 
        background:url(http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/ball/4/g/g/vector-x-football-england-100x100-imade784dbrjbdzp.jpeg) no-repeat 50% 99% #EEEEEE;
        background-size:25px
    }
#main-nav a:nth-child(2){
    background:url(http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/BRILLIANT/sports/jpg/128/american_football_icon.jpg) no-repeat 50% 99% #EEEEEE;
    background-size:25px
}
#main-nav a:nth-child(3){
    background:url(http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/BRILLIANT/sports/jpg/128/archery_icon.jpg) no-repeat 50% 99% #EEEEEE;
    background-size:25px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UzZaQ/2/)**

**[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/UzZaQ/5/)**

Comment: yes Just what i am looking for but i want every button have different icon, how to work with this?

Comment: @Mostafa Biomy instead of `CSS nth-type` I would rather add some classes to those buttons, so it would be more clear to read and to undertand for You, besides, if You will have to change order it won't mess up

Comment: @bumerang FYI nth-child is used to reduce the usage of multiple classes

Comment: @Sowmya you mean to make every button has its own class is it will be upper to `CSS nth-type` ?

Comment: @MostafaBiomy Adding multiple class can make your html heavy, that is y pseudo classes are used

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
    <div id='main-nav'> <a href="./football.html">Football<div class='icon'></div></a>

<a href="./basketball-.html">Basketball<div class='icon'></div></a>

<a href="./baseball.html">Baseball<div class='icon'></div></a> 
</div>
```

whit this css:

```
#main-nav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 125px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px #C0C0C0 solid;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 106px;
    height: 78px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    position : relative;
}
#main-nav a .icon {
    height: 30px;
    width : 30px;
    background : red;//change this for the img.
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left  : 35px;
}
#main-nav a:hover, #main-nav .active {
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    border: 1px #C0C0C0 solid;
}
```

Changing the red background for a `background: url(/path/to/image)`

Please, take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctnE6/).

Note: include a `<div>` intro a `<a>` it's valid in html5 but not in html 4.01. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct).

Comment: tried it but the red color goes below the button not inside it why?

Comment: Have you added  `position : relative;` to `#main-nav a` ??

Comment: its still `position : absolute;`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you... The '#main-nav a' must have position:relative and the '#main-nav a .icon' position:absolute. If you still have problems, could you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try this. your html

```
<div id="main-nav">
  <a href="#" class="football">Football</a>
  <a href="#" class="cricket">Cricket</a>
  <a href="#" class="tennis">Tennis</a>
</div>
```

css

```
#main-nav a
 {     
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 125px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #666666;
  border: 1px #C0C0C0 solid;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 106px;
  height: 78px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 78px;
  padding-left:50px;
 }

 #main-nav a.football{
background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ampeross/qetto/32/icon-developer-icon.png") no-repeat 10px;
}
 #main-nav a.cricket{
background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/3d-cartoon/32/Axialis-Icon-Workshop-icon.png") no-repeat 10px;
}
#main-nav a.tennis{
background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/mac-folders/32/Blue-Apple-icon.png") no-repeat 10px;
}
#main-nav a:hover, #main-nav .active
 {
  color: #666666;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border: 1px #C0C0C0 solid; 
}
```

my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ponrajpaul/4VMa4/

or if you want to use same icon for all links, remove all class names from a tags and use like this

```
<div id="main-nav">
 <a href="#">Football</a>
 <a href="#">Cricket</a>
 <a href="#">Tennis</a>
<div>


#main-nav a{
background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/3d-cartoon/32/Axialis-Icon-Workshop-icon.png") no-repeat 10px;
}
```

> a:nth-child(numbers) will not support in ie6. If you dont need ie old
>   browsers support, nth-child method is best to you..